# How to print RMarkdown chunk code output in Console?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

As I test my R code in a chunk in R Markdown, I want *all* my `print` outputs to be shown in  separate console window (not only below the code chunk, which is way down below, because my chunk is long – so I can’t easily view it)

I noted that in code below

````
---
title: "How to  print rmarkdown code chunk output in Console?"
output: html_document
---

 ```{r}
 names(mtcars) 
 print(mtcars)
````

the print output of the first line is actually displayed both in Editor window below the chunk and in Console (see below)– that’s great.
However the print output of the second line (as of any list) is not shown in Console – and that’s very inconvenient.

```
> names(mtcars) 
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
[11] "carb"
> print(mtcars)
```

Is there a trick to address this inconvenience?

Comment: This seems like an [tag:rstudio]-specific issue, is that right? (Not everybody uses RStudio to use R.)

Comment: What do you use for coding in R?

Comment: I use emacs/ess. Others use Rterm (wickedly low-tech), Visual Studio, or Jupyter notebooks (there are likely more I'm missing, no flame wars please :-). While the RStudio IDE might be (idk!) the most populous for interactive R use, too many people confound them, and RStudio != R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools > Global Options > R Markdown, and untick "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents".

```
> names(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
> print(head(mtcars))
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```